# Wildcard Operators to exclude all number before and after a character

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I would like to find all the addresses like VIA BOEZIO 6.
I've used:

```
select address
from tab
where address like '%VIA%BOEZIO%6%'
```

but unfortunately this is the result:

[image]

Is there a way to exclude all numeric characters before and after "6".
Could you help me?

Thanks
Mattia

Edit:
I've fixed with:

where address similar to '%VIA%BOEZIO%[^0-9]6[^0-9]%'

Comment: What "8"?  I don't see "8" in any of the rows.

Comment: Please include your content as text, not as a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
SELECT address
FROM tab
WHERE address LIKE '%VIA%BOEZIO_6%';
```

This uses `_` to accept just a single character between `BOEZIO` and the number `6`.  This would only match:

```
VIA BOEZIO 6
VIA BOEZIO 6A
```

Comment: I should include any data that contain VIA BOEZIO 6. 
I would like to obtain this list:

-VIA BOEZIO 6
-VIA BOEZIO 6A
-VIA BOEZIO,6
-VIA BOEZIO, 6 Pizza

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want `regexp_like()`:

```
select address
from tab
where regexp_like(address, 'VIA BOEZIO[^0-9]*6')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will guarantee that there isn't additional digit before or **after** the '6'.
It also allows you to have any combination of non-alphanumeric characters between 'BOEZIO' and '6'.

```
select address
from   tab
where  regexp_like(address, 'VIA BOEZIO(\W|_)+6(\D|$)')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5fd8e/1/0)